# Styling jQuery Data Table Search Panel

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I just discovered data table search panel but too impressed with the styling. I have searched the documentation for applying styles but couldn't get this to work:

```
var tblItems = $("#itemsTable").DataTable({
    jQueryUI: true,
    data: [],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'searchPanes',
            config: {
            //dtOpts: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 5 ],
                layout: 'columns-4',
                hideCount: false,
                info: false,
                controls: true,
                cascadePanes: false,
                className: 'myCustomClass'
            }
        },
```

Short of inspecting the classes used in search panel (dtsp-xxx) and overriding them, how can I apply styles to the panels (font-size, color, bootstrap classes, ...)?

I set something ridiculous to myCustomClass like thick red borders and teal background color to easily see if it is applied and it is not.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is somewhat limited - but this may help:

I added the following to my DataTable:

```
columnDefs:[{
  searchPanes:{
    className: 'myCustomClass'
  },
  targets: '_all'
}]
```

This added the class name to each panel in the search pane.

Then I added a very basic style:

```
<style>
.myCustomClass div.dataTables_scroll {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
}
</style>
```

This targets the scrollable area in each pane:

[image]

A couple of notes:

1. I have never placed the search pane in a button control - nice! But I do notice that (for me) doing this throws a couple of errors in the browser console, which do not happen when the search pane is not in a button. Not sure if that interferes with any functionality.
2. It's a bit counter-intuitive (to me) that you have to add the class name to a `columnDefs` value like this. It works, but it's also possible that there may be a better way.

Comment: My example also sets the 'className' to myCustomClass. The only difference is that I have it in a button control because I didn't want to pane to be open all the time. Maybe that's the problem, a different syntax required when search pane is triggered by the button? I will give columnDefs a try and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: My example also has the panel in a button. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: OK, it works for, as you mentioned, content in the scrollable area of the panel. It applies to outer part of the panels inside the pane when I remove div.dataTableScroll. I think this is probably the extent I can go without modifying searchPane's own classes.

Comment: @joshmoto thanks but these changes apply to the dom. I appreciate the response but I was looking specifically to modify search pane's styles.